# why am I getting an type error in my Python generator?

Tags: python-3.x, iterator, generator

I am working on LeetCode problem 173 in Python 3 and trying to use a generator to implement a iterator for enumerating the values of nodes in a binary tree in "infix order".  I encounter an error "type error: 'int' object is not callable" and do not understand what the issue is.  Here's my code:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class BSTIterator:
    # self.next is the next node to be returned when "next" is called, or None
    # when exhausted
    def __init__(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]):
        self.iter = self.traverse( root )
        self.next = next( self.iter )

    def next(self) -> int:
        assert self.hasNext()
        node = self.next
        try:
            self.next = next( self.iter )
        except StopIteration:
            self.next = None
        return node        

    def hasNext(self) -> bool:
        return self.next != None 
    
    def traverse( self, node ):
        if node != None:
            yield from self.traverse( node.left )
            yield node.val
            yield from self.traverse( node.right )

# Your BSTIterator object will be instantiated and called as such:
# obj = BSTIterator(root)
# param_1 = obj.next()
# param_2 = obj.hasNext()
```

Comment: Please provide the _full_ stack trace (which includes the line on which the error occured) and a [mre] that replicates your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, the stack trace (at least what I can see of it) is not very useful, all calls inside the Python implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the name `next` for two purposes in your class. It's both a method, and a data value. The issue is that the value shadows the method, so when you try calling `self.next()`, you're trying to call an integer.

Pick a different name for the data value, and the code should work:

```
class BSTIterator:
    def __init__(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]):
        self.iter = self.traverse( root )
        self.next_val = next( self.iter )           # use a new attribute name

    def next(self) -> int:                          # so you don't shadow this method
        assert self.hasNext()
        node = self.next_val                        # update the name here
        try:
            self.next_val = next( self.iter )       # and here
        except StopIteration:
            self.next_val = None                    # here too
        return node

    def hasNext(self) -> bool:
        return self.next_val != None                # and in this method
    
    # the traverse method doesn't need any changes
```

If we use the `TreeNode` definition from the comments in the question code, we can test this out:

```
>>> tree = TreeNode(1, TreeNode(0), TreeNode(2))

>>> it = BSTIterator(tree)

>>> it.next()
0

>>> it.next()
1

>>> it.hasNext()
True

>>> it.next()
2

>>> it.hasNext()
False
```

Comment: Yes, @Pranav Hosangadi, I was about to say the same thing.   I guess I don't understand how Python is handling name resolution...   In any case, I will try Blckknght 's solution.

Comment: The comments at the end of the code in the question tell us how the code should be run. They include `obj.next()`, which is presumably what's causing the `TypeError` (you'd get the same from `1()`). I've just realized that my name is actually misleading, since the `next` value being assigned isn't a node object, but the `val` attribute from a node. A name like `next_val` might be better than `next_node`. (I've now updated the question with the better name.)